# Issues with "QUERY(IMPORTRANGE)"

Tags: import, google-sheets-formula

Here's my first question on this forum, though I've read through a lot of good answers here.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my attempt to do a query import from one sheet to a column in another?

Here's the formula I've tried, but all my adjustments still get me a parsing error.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGPdI0eBRNltMQ3Wr8E2cw-wNlysZd-XY3mtAnEyLLY/edit#gid=163356401","Master Treatment Log (Responses)!V2:V")"WHERE Col8="'&B2&'")")

Answer (score 0):

Note that importrange is only needed for imports between spreadsheets. If you only import from one sheet into another within the same spreadsheet I would suggest using filter() or query().

Assuming the value in B2 is actually a string (and not a number), you can try

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGPdI0eBRNltMQ3Wr8E2cw-wNlysZd-XY3mtAnEyLLY/edit#gid=163356401","Master Treatment Log (Responses)!V2:V"), "WHERE Col8="'&B2&'", 0)
```

Note the added comma before "WHERE". If you want to import a header row, change 0 to 1.

See if that helps? If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased).